# How to replace multiple letters in an variable in Sieve?

Tags: email, dovecot, filter, sieve

I want to use my catch-all-email to put emails in their corresponding folders. So if I were to sign up for twitter I'd use twitter@example.com.
Currently I have this script:

```
if address :matches ["To", "Cc"] "*@example.com" {
 fileinto :create "INBOX/@example.com/${1}";
}
```

That seems to work. However, I for another catch-all I use the mail I rot13 the local part. So it would be gjvggre@example.com. Now the question is: Can I undo this rot13 with sieve? If so how?

Sieve extensions I have access to: `fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date index ihave duplicate mime foreverypart extracttext vacation-seconds editheader imapflags notify imapsieve vnd.dovecot.imapsieve vnd.dovecot.pgp-encrypt`